# How to search by filename in windows 10?

Tags: search

I know I can use 'name' keyword but is there a way to make it default behavior?

Right now my searches show thousands of result when there is in fact only 2 or 3 files with the name.I think it is searching the contents. Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: I have always just type the name of the file.  No extra filtering required.  Have you tried that? (All versions of Windows has worked this way)

Comment: As i have said ,when i do it it shows hundreds of result

Comment: Might help if you provide an example.  You shouldn’t be getting thousands of results, even a system file, would be limited to a couple dozen

Comment: Some screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: I did not literally mean thousand but more like hundred.sometimes less sometimes more.Apparently it is also searching in the contents I guess

Comment: Are searching with Cortana instead of File Explorer?  If you mean hundreds say hundreds, even hundreds is off, because if I search for a filename I know exist I don’t have that problem

Comment: No i just type in the search bar in explorer

Comment: Default behavior of Windows Search is to search all known attributes of a file for the query term. OP appears to be wanting to search only the filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Windows default search supports a few keywords for filtering searches based on specific attributes.

To search only file names, use

```
filename: <query>
```

You can also use **kind:** to search files of different extensions that are of a similar kind (video, music, documents, etc), **type:** to specify a specific file extension, or **size:**.

Comment: yes i know about that but i want it to be default befaviour.Right now when I search for a file named "house" it will also list a text file named "random.txt" just because it contains a word "house" inside

Comment: However, the answer to that question will be "no". Besides the few options available in Folder Properties > Search, which do not include limiting the default search behavior to a specified keyword(s), there is no option in the current edition of Windows 10 to do this.

Comment: (Or any version of Windows)

Comment: @music2myear the word default is clearly mentioned in my question.Anyway i dont understand how it can be so difficult.I mean if I want to search a file named "and" ,then hundreds of text files on my pc will contain this common word and i will get a big list of result.There has to be a way to avoid this.

Comment: You're right. I didn't see that "default" in the first line until I read it just now. I stand corrected. Wanting something to be the case is not the same thing as it being the case. I assume there are third-party search utilities still available that may offer this feature, but limiting ourselves to the options to change the default search behavior in the built-in Windows Search does not give us these options.

Comment: I cannot be the only one who gets irritated by this.Why this has not been discussed before ?

Comment: No, it's not likely you're the only one, but SuperUser is not where you submit feature requests to Microsoft, and as I mentioned before, wanting something to be a certain way is no good reason for it to be that way, much less proof it IS that way.